# Unit test case for email in grails(email:true)

Tags: email, testing, grails, junit

Can any  one help me out to write unit test case for email in grails(email:true)?

contactName(maxSize:25)
contactEmail(maxSize:50,email:true)

Answer (score 0):

Grails have a [section in the documentation about unit testing](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains). Check the "Testing Constraints".

Example:

```
class Person {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name matches: /[A-Z].*/
    }
}

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(Person)
class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    void "Test that name must begin with an upper case letter"() {
        when: 'the name begins with a lower letter'
        def p = new Person(name: 'jeff')

        then: 'validation should fail'
        !p.validate()

        when: 'the name begins with an upper case letter'
        p = new Person(name: 'Jeff')

        then: 'validation should pass'
        p.validate()
    }
}
```